# How do I use prodlim function with a non-binary variable in formula?

Tags: r

I am trying to (eventually) plot data by groups, using the prodlim function.
I'm adjusting and adapting code that someone else (not available for questions) has written, and I'm not very familiar with the prodlim library/function.  There are definitely other ways to do what I'd like to, but I'm trying to keep it consistent with what the previous person did.
I have code that works, when dividing the data into 2 groups, but when I try to adjust for a 4 group situation, I get an error.
Of note, the data is coming over from SAS using StatTransfer, which has been working fine.

I am new to coding, but I have compared the dataframes I'm trying to work with.  The second is just a subset of the first (where the code does work), with all the same variables, and both of the variables I'm trying to group by are integer values.
`Hist(medpop$dz_time, medpop$dz_status)` works just fine, so the problem must be with the prodlim function, and I haven't understood much of what I've looked up about it, sadly :/  But it the documentation seems to indicate it supports continuous or categorical variables, and doesn't seem limited to binary either.  None of the options seem applicable as I understand them.

this works:

```
M <- prodlim(Hist(dz_time, dz_status)~med, data=pop)
```

where med is a binary value =1 when a member of this population is taking it, and dz is a disease that some portion develop.

this does not:
(either of these get the error as below)

```
N <- prodlim(Hist(dz_time, dz_status)~strength, data=medpop)
N <- prodlim(Hist(dz_time, dz_status)~strength, data=pop, subset=pop$med==1)
```

medpop = the subset of the original population taking the med,
strength = categorical variable ("1","2","3","4")

For the line that does work, the next step is just `plot(M)`, giving a plot with two lines, med==0 and med==1 (showing cumulative incidence of dz_status by dz_time).

For the other line, I get an error saying
`Error in KernSmooth::dpik(cumtabx/N, kernel = "box") :
scale estimate is zero for input data`

I don't know what that means or how to fix it.. :/